# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to fix this error:

```
  File "lcd3.py", line 54
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc4' in file lcd3.py on line 54, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Adding this line doesn't change anything:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Could you show the line that causes the error?

Comment: ` # definicja poszczegolnych liter - kolejno: spacja, ą, ę, ł, ó `

Comment: Do you absolutely need the comment? And also, you can put `#!/usr/bin/python` before

Comment: No. I deleting this comment, and i have same problem in another line:  lcd_string(u"i mamy PL znaki: ą ę ł ó")

Comment: Sorry i cant write normal code, but this site dont have options for it...

Comment: Yes it does, put your code in backticks (``)

Comment: How are you running your code, and what os are you on?

Comment: I starting script like that: `sudo python lcd3.py` and i using rpi with raspbian

Comment: Here is my code: https://codeshare.io/GkbnOx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding both of these to the beginning of your code, and take out what you have right now at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Note to OP: these must be at the very top of the file, no comments, no other lines before these two.

Comment: Change nothing.

Comment: Did you take out the comments you had at the top?